# Case Object with 2 Self Lookups to Cases - Considerations

Tags: case, lookup, largedatavolumes

We have functionality around Moves(Shipping request from one location to another) , claims and service requests for one of our clients.

we are planning to put all 3 of them in Salesforce Case object and differentiate them using record types.

Claims will have lookup to Move(self lookup) and Service requests will have 2 self look-ups(move and claims)

With all 3 record types the total number of fields will not exceed 150. 
per year total number of records including all 3 types will be around 800,000 and we will archive any record older than 2 years.

The reason we are thinking of using case for all 3 is to use standard case features like entitlement process and milestone which all 3 functionality needs.

Are they any considerations/major flaws with this approach specially around data volumes,SOQL references?

Comment: N.B. `Case.ParentId` is an existing field that you could choose to use for one of the self-lookups

Comment: Thank you @cropredy, will definitely consider that

Comment: Will there be only one "Claims" case per Service Request?  And are Claims mainly associated with Moves, Service Requests, or both?  I'm just having a tough time visualizing a hierarchy (if there is one) here

Comment: There is no hierarchy. On claims, there will be a lookup to move and on service request there will be lookups to claims and moves.

Comment: From design perspective I don't think you have an issue here *unless* you see a scenario which leads you to a [Parent-Child Data Skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_parent_child_data_skew.htm). In any data model design you will primarily need to look at the [Ownership skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership_data_skew.htm) and Parent-Child skew for performance issues when you are dealing with volume. As long as you don't have that issue here, this model should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One area to think about (not sure how important) is the Account Case relations. With 1.6m records, I'd be wary of hitting the 10k or less best practice for lookups( and master-details) that have impacts on visibility. This may not matter depending upon the how many moves/service/claims requests per account or if you sharing settings are public read-write on case/account. Separate object is one way to alleviate this concern.

Another area to examine is your required fields/validation rules. Using record types to represent whole sperate ideas (not just variation) can make required fields and validation rules somewhat tricky to write, especially without needed to check record type within rules.

Another area of concern is visibility in general. Since the simplest visibility to enforce/validate is object level, I would just ensure that visibility requirements are being done along the record type axis.

Lastly, to the point of SOQL/SOSL and data volumes. SOQL will be helped by using the RecordTypeId field whenever possible as it already index and can help with query planning. Search will present a diffrent issue in the the UI will return all types and limits per object may present issues with searching. SOSL will present some similar issues as requests are filtered after search (ie recordTypeId = claim) which may ensure you get small/weaker search results then you expect.

Comment: +1..Nice points around validation rules and required fields.